# Hadoop: getting container launched failed error

Tags: java, hadoop

I have freshly installed a multinode hadoop cluster with one namenode machine, and two slavenodes. However, when I run a mapreduce task, I keep getting this error:

Container launch failed for container_1453020503065_0030_01_000009

```
:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:java.net.UnknownHostException: HOME
```

Here HOME and shubhranshu-OptiPlex-9020 are hostname of slave machines. I have put their IP address and hostname in /etc/hosts file. 
My /etc/hosts file look like this:

```
10.0.3.107  HadoopMaster
10.0.3.108  HadoopSlave1
10.0.3.109  HadoopSlave2
127.0.0.1       localhost amrit
#127.0.1.1      amrit
10.0.3.107      amrit
10.0.3.108      HOME
10.0.3.109      shubhranshu-OptiPlex-9020
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Please tell if I need to add some more things. Thank You!

Comment: Did you syncronize your /etc/hosts file between all hosts of your cluster? Is there a good reason to have duplicate hostnames?

Comment: Between all hosts, the first 3 lines are synchronized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your /etc/hosts file as follows:

```
    127.0.0.1       localhost 
    10.0.3.107      HadoopMaster amrit
    10.0.3.108      HadoopSlave1
    10.0.3.109      HadoopSlave2
```

Also modify /etc/hosts of 10.0.3.108 machine as follows:

```
    127.0.0.1       localhost 
    10.0.3.107      HadoopMaster 
    10.0.3.108      HadoopSlave1 HOME
    10.0.3.109      HadoopSlave2
```

and modify /etc/hosts in 10.0.3.109 machine as follows:

```
    127.0.0.1       localhost 
    10.0.3.107      HadoopMaster 
    10.0.3.108      HadoopSlave1
    10.0.3.109      HadoopSlave2 shubhranshu-OptiPlex-9020
```